# How to make the icon in TextFormField enabled in code?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have set a color to an `icon` in a `TextFormField`, but the color only comes when the `TextFormField` is focused.

How do I set it so that upon a `setState()` the `icon` stays 'focused' or colored?

Comment: When do you want that color to be shown? Both on unfocused and focused?

Comment: @MinjinGelegdorj I have a controller so I am setting a boolean upon `onChanged` so that it becomes true when the field is not empty. So only when the field is not empty, the icon should be colored and stay colored even when unfocused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
bool _textIsEmpty = true;
TextEditingController _controller= TextEditingController();
... // rest of your code

TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.abc,
      color: _textIsEmpty ? Colors.transparent : Colors.pink,
    ),
  ),
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _textIsEmpty = value.isEmpty;
    });
  },
),
```